# Editing config.txt in boot.tar.xz in Windows

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspi-config

I am new to Raspberry Pi and I have downloaded the NOOBS setup zip file. I am using an HDMI to VGA converter to display contents on my monitor. It seems I need to edit the `config.txt` file to make it work. I have found the file in `boot.tar.xz` which opens using WinRAR. I am also able to edit the file using Notepad.

However when I save the file and open it again the edits are reverted to the original state. How do I edit the `config.txt` file?

Thanks.

Comment: Super user elevation is required to edit config. The boot partition should be fat32 and therefore readable in Windows. Or, while booted to your desired OS, CTRL+ALT+T for a Terminal window then input; sudo nano /boot/config.txt

Answer (score 2):

First copy the file to the desktop, edit it, then drag and drop it in the folder opened with WinRar.

Answer (score -1):

Use 7-zip. Here's the download link: http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: Will it work? This page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) says that XZ is not compatible with 7zip.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Try it yourself.

Comment: If you don't know that it works, then you should not present it as answer.

Comment: @Ingo It did work back then, and it still works now. This was over 3 years ago, and I admit my rhetoric could have been much better.